# What does each of the following codes in a HTML file mean?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, types

```
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Gone!'"> 
Click Me!</button> <button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Back again!'">
Bring me back!</button>
```

Can someone explain what each line means?

Comment: First line means there is a button, onclick of  that button; find element in the document with an id 'msg' and make it's text 'Gone!'. The other line same as the first one.

Comment: @B.Yaylaci Thank you i understand it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click of buttons it will search for the element with id="msg" and set its inner HTML i.e. content of the element.

https://jsfiddle.net/night11/qs3sL6qt/1/

```
<p id="msg">My first paragraph</p>
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Gone!'"> 
Click Me!</button> <button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Back again!'">
Bring me back!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
<button type="button"
    onclick="document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Gone!'"> 
    Click Me!</button> <button type="button"
    onclick="document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Back again!'">
    Bring me back!</button>
```

Both of these buttons are used to "find" an HTML element (with id="msg"),
 and changes the element content (innerHTML) to "Gone!" in first button and "Back again!" in second button.
 Got it.